# How to click on anchor <a> tag from Canoo webtest?

Tags: xpath, anchor, web-testing, canoo, canoo-webtest

Our team replaced a submit button with the following anchor tag:

```
<a class="l-btn" onclick="onFormSubmit(this.form)" Style="width: 80px; text-align:center;"> 
<span class="l-btn-left"> 
<span class="l-btn-text">Save</span> 
</span>
</a>
```

I retrieved xpath from XPather, and tried to use  from canoo webtest to click on it, but received "failed: Link not found".

Does anyone know how to simulate click on the above?

Thanks.

Comment: What if you add an HREF?

Answer (score 0):

```
<clickLink xpath="//a[@class='l-btn']" description="Click first a tag with class l-btn" />
```

See [clickLink documentation](http://webtest.canoo.com/webtest/manual/clickLink.html)

Answer (score 0):

`clickLink xpath="//a[contains(@onclick,'onFormSubmit')]`

```
description="click link with onclick property that contain the word
onFormSubmit"
```

will look for the link with `xpath` property `onclick` that contain a value `'onFormSubmit'`